# Weird behaviour between offscreenCanvas, getImageData and drawImage

Tags: javascript, web, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm developing a react drawing application and I encounter many performance bottlenecks.

I decieded to make some tests in vanilla JS.
I now have a weird behaviour.
Here is the code (I tried to simplify it at a maximum).

```js
function initCanvas(ctx) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
}

function getPictureCoordinates(event) {
    let targetRect = event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    let pictureX = Math.floor((event.clientX - targetRect.left) * (image.naturalWidth / targetRect.width));
    let pictureY = Math.floor((event.clientY - targetRect.top) * (image.naturalHeight / targetRect.height));
    return { x: pictureX, y: pictureY };
}

let currentCoordinates = [];
let drawing = false;

const containerElement = document.querySelector('#innerContainer2');

let image = document.querySelector('#mainImage');

let mainCanvas = document.querySelector('#mainCanvas');
mainCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', drawingClicked);
mainCanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
mainCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', endDrawing);

mainCanvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
mainCanvas.height = image.naturalHeight;


let mainCtx = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');


initCanvas(mainCtx);

function drawingClicked(event) {
    startDrawing(event);
}

function startDrawing(event) {
    mainCtx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
    mainCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

    mainCtx.beginPath();
    const { x, y } = getPictureCoordinates(event);
    currentCoordinates.push([{ x, y }]);
    mainCtx.lineWidth = 20;
    mainCtx.moveTo(x, y);
    drawing = true;
    draw({ x: x + 1, y: y + 1 });
}

function mouseMove(event) {
    const movePoint = getPictureCoordinates(event);
    if (drawing) {
        draw(movePoint);
    }
}

function draw(point) {
    currentCoordinates.push(point);
    mainCtx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
    mainCtx.stroke();
}

function endDrawing(event) {
    if (!drawing) return;
    drawing = false;
    currentCoordinates = [];
}
```

This allows me to make some basic drawings.
I turned on the option "Paint Flashing" in the Rendering tab of Chrome debug tool and here is what I get:

[image]

We can see that only the area of  the currently drawing stroke is refreshed.

Now say that I want to make a pixel operation at the end of the drawing.

I'm adding this at the end of `endDrawing` function :

```js
let ctx = mainCanvas.getContext('2d', { willReadFrequently: true });
ctx.getImageData(0, 0, mainCanvas.width, mainCanvas.height);
```

Now, after the second stroke, any new drawing triggers the rendering of the whole canvas.

[image]

After many experimentations, I found something:
I add at the begining of the code:

```js
...

mainCanvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
mainCanvas.height = image.naturalHeight;

let offScreenCanvas = new OffscreenCanvas(image.naturalWidth, image.naturalHeight);
let offscreenCtx = offScreenCanvas.getContext('2d');
initCanvas(offscreenCtx);

let ctx = mainCanvas.getContext('2d', { willReadFrequently: true });
ctx.getImageData(0, 0, mainCanvas.width, mainCanvas.height);

let mainCtx = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');

mainCtx.drawImage(offScreenCanvas, 0, 0);

initCanvas(mainCtx);
...
```

And now it works again like a charm!

But I don't understand!

First, why doing a `getImageData` would make the whole canvas refresh (and only after the second stroke!).

Then, why adding an offscreenCanvas, drawing it in the main canvas but not using it anymore would solve my problem?
And more of that! If I don't do the initial `getImageData` on the main canvas (right after initializing the `offscreenCtx`), it does not work!

This is really frustrating.
Has any of you have an idea on why do I have those weird behaviours?

Thanks!

**EDIT 21/07**

I have this behaviour:

- in Chrome 114.0.5735.198 Ubuntu 22.04
- in Chrome 114.0.5735.196 Android 12 - v4.14.186+
- in Chrome 114.0.5735.198 Windows 10
- in Edge 114.0.1823.82 Windows 10
- in Brave 1.52.130 Ubuntu 22.04

I can not test on Firefox because there is no option to highlight repainted zones, but it seems that it runs more smoothly.